# error when installing python packages with PIP

Tags: python

Whenever I try to install a python package I get the following error.

```
C:\Python27>pip install pyaardvark

C:\strawberry\perl\bin/pip: Perl lib version (5.22.0) doesn't match executable '
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe' version (5.16.3) at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Conf
ig.pm line 62.
Compilation failed in require at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Errno.pm line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/Errno.pm line 8.
Compilation failed in require at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/File/Temp.pm line 148.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/strawberry/perl/lib/File/Temp.pm line 14
8.
Compilation failed in require at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/pip.pm line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:/strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/pip.pm line 6
.
Compilation failed in require at C:\strawberry\perl\bin/pip line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\strawberry\perl\bin/pip line 5.
```

Does anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PATH environment variable, your Perl directories likely preceed the Python ones, so when you call `pip`, it fires the `pip` binary located in your Strawberry Perl instance.

Try calling `pip` with its full path, eg: `c:\python27\bin\pip`. I don't have access to a Windows box at the moment, so that may not be the actual path and you'll have to find the actual location.

Comment: would you mind letting me know exactly the path and I'll update the answer accordingly? Thanks!

Comment: python27\scripts\pip